# Adobe Edge sorting your Images

Tags: image, sorting, adobe-edge

I am working on an interactive book that is made in Adobe Edge Animate and I wanted to sort the images in the "**images**" folder so i made sub folders "**common**" , "**page_01**", "**page_02**" etc. But every time I save my project it takes all the images out of the subfolders and place it in the root "**images**" folder. How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a test and it's working for me.
That is what I did:

1. Created a new subfolder called "test" inside the images subfolder (not the one inside publish!!)
2. Put there my test.png image.
3. Added projectFolder/images/test/test.png to the assets. I can see the subfolder in the Library > Assets panel.
4. Dragged and dropped the image in the stage.
5. Saved the project
6. Published the project
7. The image test.png is always inside its subfolder.

Comment: Please note that when you use the image in the stage, on the Property panel you can see the path: images%5Ctest/test.png

Comment: It works for me 2 following your steps. The only thing that i can say why didn't it worked before is that i probably imported the images from another folder and then tryed to sort them in the images folder

Comment: Yes, that will not work. The key point is the image being in the right path when you import it in the assets.

Comment: Every time I place a folder in "the images" folder the path of the image becomes "images%5Cpage_01/image.png", "%5C" is the "\". Edge animate places it for an escape character or for what?